# Where do I set-up a screen saver in Xubuntu 15.10?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, 15.10, lock-screen, screensaver

That's strange but I can't find where can I choose a screen saver and configure when will it start. There is no button named anything like "screen saver" in the Settings Manager.

Answer (score 10):

Those settings are located in the power management settings. You can directly launch that using `xfce4-power-manager-settings`.

[image]

The blank option makes your screen display the black color but does not turn it off! I don't know what is the difference between sleep and switch off because both seem to make my monitor enter standby mode.

Answer (score 7):

The short blunt answer is sense [14.04](http://xubuntu.org/news/screen-locking-in-xubuntu-14-04/) you can not have a screen saver other then the blank black. You will have to install `xscreensaver` or `gnome-screensaver`

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe Xfce comes with a screensaver. I use the "Switch off after" setting in the Xfce Power Manager to switch off my monitor.

The "Blank after" and "Put to sleep after" settings don't give me even a blank black, but do trigger the login window as configured on the Security tab.

This is seriously non-intuitive, as the Security tab implies that Light Locker only activates "when the screensaver is active", and since nothing on the Display tab (or elsewhere) mentions a screensaver, I assumed it wasn't set up. Where's my "screensaver" setting, even if it's only for black?

Comment: What you wrote certainly isn't an answer at all, but +1 anyway for the good questions that need to be answered.

Comment: Thanks, @GabrielStaples. I tried to make it a clearer answer, though I admit it's a weak one :)